# What is the fastest way to sort 1 million integers when integers are from the range [1,100]?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Notes:  I've thought about Radix sort, bucket sort, counting sort.

Is there anyway to achieve big O(n)?

Comment: It is not possible in general to sort a list in O(n), even if every number in the list is less than 100.

Comment: @SLaks: The minimum of O(N lgN) applies only to sorts based on comparisons.

Comment: in this case you can, by simply counting elements between 1 and 100.

Comment: I do think that radix sort can achieve O(n)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

> Counting sort (sometimes referred to as ultra sort or math sort) is a sorting algorithm which (like bucket sort) takes advantage of knowing the range of the numbers in the array to be sorted (array A).
>
> Counting sort is a stable sort and has a running time of Θ(n+k), where n and k are the lengths of the arrays A (the input array) and C (the counting array), respectively. In order for this algorithm to be efficient, k must not be much larger than n.

In this case k is 100 and n is 1000000.

Answer (score 8):

A counting sort would be the obvious choice under these circumstances. Yes, properly implemented it should have linear complexity.

Answer (score 6):

how about just counting the occurrence of each integer and then printing them all. sounds like O(n)

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly counting sort. This shows that most algorithms aren't hard; you can come up with them yourself. :-)

Comment: counting sort is a bit more complex than that (it sorts the keys, but can handle associacted data), but yes, that's the basic idea

Answer (score 4):

I assume, you mean you want to achieve a small O(n); then bucket sort would be fastest. In fact, since you know the range of the integers, then using bucket sort simply becomes a problem of counting the occurrences of the numbers which can be done in O(n), i.e. linear time.

The so-called counting sort is simply a special case of bucket sort.

Comment: No, counting sort is not a special case of bucket sort. In bucket sort you actually store the elements in the buckets. In counting sort you only store the count.

Answer (score 2):

With counting sort you get O(N) if the range is fixed and small (like 1..100 :))

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I quickly threw together this piece of Ruby, before reading the answers:

```
module Enumerable
  def counting_sort(k)
    reduce(Array.new(k+1, 0)) {|counting, n| counting.tap { counting[n] += 1 }}.
    map.with_index {|count, n| [n] * count }.flatten
  end
end

ary = Array.new(1_000_000){ rand(100) + 1 }
ary.counting_sort(100) # I'll spare you the output :-)
```

I didn't even know it had a name. It should convey the idea even to someone who has never seen Ruby before. (The only thing you need to know is that the K combinator is spelled `tap` in Ruby.)

And it really is pretty darn fast, although unfortunately I have not been able to beat the builtin hand-optimized O(n log n) sort, which is written in C in MRI and YARV and Java in JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counting sort in scala:

```
val res = Array.fill (100)(0)
val r = util.Random 
// generate data to sort
val nums = for (i <- 1 to 1000*1000) yield r.nextInt (100)
for (i <- nums) res(i) += 1
println (res.mkString (" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Radix Sort (In Ruby):

```
def sort(array)
sorted_array = Array.new(100,[])
array.each do |t|
sorted_array[t-1] = sorted_array[t-1] + [t]
end
sorted_array.flatten!
end
```