# Best data structure to store one million values?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Please mention time complexity and best data structure to store these values, when values are:

1. Integers
2. Strings (dictionary like sorting)

I know [Counting sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311053/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-sort-1-million-integers-when-integers-are-from-the-ran) is preferred when integers are in a small range.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I asked a bit different question. Actual question is what would be the best data structure to store these values, if the integers are phone numbers (and strings are names) and then find the best sorting algorithm.

Comment: Anybody else smell homework?

Comment: A million items is a fairly average number by current standards -- the usual criteria for selecting (no pun intended) a sorting algorithm are likely to apply.

Comment: @Justin - Is it that time of year again already?  @understack - the SO community doesn't mind helping with homework questions, heck if we could live vicariously through college in other ways, I am sure we would, but we would like to see what effort you have put forth already before we go off an do your homework for you (e.g I have looked @ bubblesort and quicksort, but I am not sure which would be faster for these options b/c of the storage mechanisms involved).

Comment: For a million values, I'd just do it by hand.

Comment: You should just ask another question.  The topic is "Fastest way to sort"

Comment: Never store phone numbers as ints.  They are not integers.  They just happen to use characters from 0-9 most of the time.

Comment: With the possible exception of a linked list, there are no data structures whose attributes would select it based on the number of values. Size isn't a relevant consideration. Wanting to have or keep your values is a consideration bearing on a possible data structure, but that's not your question either. Until you understand the assignment well enough to ask a relevant question, please stop wasting people's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:
[Btrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

You should be able to find open source implementations of each of these.  (Note, I'm assuming that you want to maintain a sorted structure, rather than just sorting once and forgetting.)

Answer (score 2):

Sorting algorithms wiki link: [Sorting Algorithm Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Merge sort and quick sort are pretty good, they are n log n in best cases.

Comment: I think I didn't ask my question correctly. Focus was on storing the values.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)? Relatively easy to implement and pretty fast. For strings, you could use a Trie along with something like Burst sort which is supposedly the fastest string sorting algorithm in its class.

Answer (score 0):

For most sorting algorithms there is an in-place version, so a simple array may be sufficient. For Strings you may consider a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie, which could save space. The right sorting algorithm depends on a lot of factors, e.g. if the results may be already sorted or partially sorted. Of course if you have just a few different values, Countingsort, Bucketsort etc can be used.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit machine, a million integers can fit in an array of 4 million bytes. 4MB isn't all that much; it'll fit in this system's memory 500 times over (and it's not that beefy by modern standards). A million strings will be the same size, except for the storage space for those strings; for short strings it's still no problem, so slurp it all in. You can even have an array of pointers to structures holding an integer and a reference to a string; it will all fit just fine. It's only when you're dealing with much more data than that (e.g., a billion items) that you need to take special measures, data-structure-wise.

For sorting that many things, choose an algorithm that is O(*n*log*n*) instead of one that is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). The O(*n*) algorithms are only useful when you've got particularly compact key spaces, which is pretty rare in practice. Choosing which algorithm from the set that are in O(*n*log*n*) is a matter of balancing speed and other good properties such as stability.

If you're doing this for real, use a database with appropriate indices instead of futzing around with doing this all by hand.