# Sorting an array containing million numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is an interview question & I'm looking wht experts can answer in a better way...

How do you sort an array containing million numbers in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Tell me your answer and I'll tell you mine.

Comment: May be `Arrays.sort(Object[])`: [Java Doc For Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: I mentioned about using circular sort but I'm not sure...But the interviewer was not expecting this answer.

Comment: what is 'circular sort'?

Comment: Already Discussed at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127030/how-to-sort-million-billion-integers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311053/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-sort-1-million-integers-when-integers-are-from-the-ran

Comment: Check out bubblesort. No really the best algoritm would depend on the data - how well ordered are they and what are the range of size. Also the hardware should be taken into consideration, ram and cpu etc.

Comment: Muleskinner : never use BubbleSort for anything; especially not for millions of items. If I was interviewing you and you mentioned BubbleSort, it would be a short interview!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interview questions never have the right answer. 
The interviewers taught to ask open-end questions to see how you think and reason about problem.
You, in your turn, should show process of thinking and demonstrate that you can think in "software engineering way".

Something like that:

1. Oh ... 1 million numbers ...
2. I think they are simple long so 1 million will take about 4 megabytes of memory
3. (Hm ... might be I am wrong here and the long will take 8 bytes so it will be 8 Mbytes ... - it's not so important right now for that problem).
4. We are able to load it to the memory and use ready algorith Arrays.sort(long[])
5. (I do know my tools and core libs).
6. It will be no extra memory and O(n*log(n)) complexity (6 000 000 operations btw).
7. Can you do it faster ?
8. Oh ... I remember that I heard about Radix sort - that algorithm gives us o(k*n) complexity where the k is number of significant ditigs (for long it will be twice as integer (2 billion = 9 digits) = 18 digits) so it will be 18 * 1 million = oh ... it will be 3 times slower and I am not sure how much additional memory the algorithm will require.
9. If we have so much data that it will overflow the available memory?
10. We will chop data into l chunks size of m so each of chunks will fit into memory
11. We will sort each chunk separatedly and store results to files
12. Merging of sorted files will be with o(m) speed
13. And we will need to perform l-1 such merges
14. etc.

Comment: Won't 1M 32-bit (4 byte) integers make it around 4000MBytes, in which case we won't necessarily load the entire data on the memory I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JVM "experts"' way:

```
Arrays.sort(numberArray);
```

Comment: Why not?  It is the simplest answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

since it's integers and there's a million of them - radix sort, in-place and on as many threads as there are CPUs available

Answer (score 0):

**Storing Millions of data in array is not good idea**. It may cause MemoryOutOfBounds Exception. It will cause performance issue. 
But if you want to sort an array

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {4, 1, 3, -23};
Arrays.sort(intArray);
// [-23, 1, 3, 4]

String[] strArray = new String[] {"z", "a", "C"};
Arrays.sort(strArray);
// [C, a, z]

// Case-insensitive sort
Arrays.sort(strArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
// [a, C, z]

// Reverse-order sort
Arrays.sort(strArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
// [z, a, C]

// Case-insensitive reverse-order sort
Arrays.sort(strArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(strArray));
// [z, C, a]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are in finite range use boolean array of 1 million. That will bring down the memory sage to 125 mb. Use index as the numbers and values as true or false. Nullify the existing array , and fill it as read through boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

We can put entries in a `NavigableHashMap` which keeps data in a sorted manner. So while putting the keys check that if a key is already present then increase the value by 1. Now while extracting the data print key multiple of value. Just that in this case we have just run through Array once that is O(N).